# Can't retrieve data from database using SOAP web service in java with WSDL (glassfish server)

Tags: java, soap, web, service, wsdl

I wanna retrieve data from mysql database using web service written in java with SOAP and WSDL I have written the code and tested it in main function and working well but when I deploy it the results is set to 0 when I use glassfish server as a client and here is the code.

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "javasamples.two.Users")
```

public class UsersImpl implements Users {

```
public int getUserCount() { 
    int numusers = 0;
    String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javasql";
    String dbClass = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String query = "Select count(*) FROM user";
    String userName = "root", password = "admin";
    try {

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection (dbUrl, userName, password);
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    while (rs.next()) {
        numusers = rs.getInt(1);
        } //end while
        con.close();
    } //end try

    catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {

        return numusers;
    }

}
```

}

and the interface code is

```
@WebService
```

@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public interface Users {

```
@WebMethod
int getUserCount();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think you should close the connection inside the try loop not in the Finally one!